# highcharts stockchart tooltip on flags switches to data series tooltip while mouse is still over flag

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, flags

In the following highchart stockchart example, you can see strange behavior when you mouse over a flag on the x axis.  it will briefly show the tooltip for the flag, but then as you continue to move the mouse over the flag square, it switches to the tooltip of the data series.  Am I missing a setting somewhere to keep showing the tooltip for the flag until you mouse out of it?

http://jsfiddle.net/gagsf83n/

```
{
            type: 'flags',
            name: 'AxisFlags',
            data: [{
                x: lastDate - 45 * days,
                title: 'On axis',
                text: 'A1'
            }, {
                x: lastDate - 15 * days,
                title: 'On axis',
                text: 'A2'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                followPointer: true
            },
            shape: 'squarepin',
            zIndex: 999
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been already fixed in the newest master-branch.

Ref:
- http://github.highcharts.com/highstock.js